# Using Geth with External Drive

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, etherscan, mainnet, eth-domain

I'm using the command

geth --http --datadir D:\NODE

but it seems like It's a wrong command, because when I switch to Localhost network on my Metamask it doesn't show the balance but when it's on Ethereum Mainnet, balance is there.

Can someone please tell me what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your node fully sync?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.